# Include path error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I love programming php, javascript and jquery. I'm implementing a project for local mobile phone shop website; however i got the error for the following code

```
        $("input[name=compareWith]").keyup(function(){
        var txt=$(this).val();
        alert(txt);
        $.post(
                "show.php",
                {data:txt},
                function(resp){

                $("div.compareWith").html(resp);

                }
            );
    });
```

What i want to do is when typing some text in input field,  it will query the database for the name and the picture of the relevant phone name via show.php file to compare it with their previous selected phone. However, the result is fine as i just tested by only put echo $_POST['data']; in show.php file .

However, above that i get this fatal error:

`Warning: include(head.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\doctorphoneshopCopy\new\show.php on line 1`

`Warning: include(): Failed opening 'head.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;c:\php\includes') in C:\wamp\www\doctorphoneshopCopy\new\show.php on line 1`

head.php is containing a database information, styling, and head session, and show.php dose is exist in my directory.

Could anyone help me with this error?

Kindly let me know should you need any further information from me,

Thanks

Comment: Well if it can't find it in that directory... then check to see where the file actually is and if its read protected.

Comment: show.php might exist, but can it find head.php? Your JS code is basically irrelevant as this is a purely server-side PHP problem.

Comment: The error isn't trying to find show.php, it's trying to find head.php. Can you show the line of code that includes head.php? I think we'll find the issue there.

Comment: Where is the include? You did not post the most important thing here.

Comment: No, all files do exists including head.php and show.php. head.php is included at the top for every file in order to work with database.

Comment: Please post the line where you include the file if you want to get help.

Comment: Hi Hecksa, here `<?php include("include/head.php");?>
<?php

$pid=$_GET["phoneid"];
//$pid=10;
$phone="Select * From phone Where phoneid=".$pid;
$rest=mysql_query($phone);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($rest);
?>` . However, that include('head.php') is working fine for the other files that use it.

Comment: I am not Hecksa. ALso pls update the questin instead of posrting it as a comment since it is unstructured now.

Comment: Also pls post the file structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to tell what the problem is cause of the missing folder structure.

You say the include works in a other file therefore the path is wrong.

```
<?php 
include("include/head.php");
?>
```

This only works if you are in the root of your applications. If you are in a sub dir for example "test" you have to do:

```
<?php 
include("../include/head.php");
?>
```

The above code will go one dir higher (to the root in this example) and then to the correct directory.

You can also use the [set_include_path()](http://de3.php.net/set_include_path) function then you don't have to worry about that path anymore.

Comment: Nice anwser. But it's a bit of guessing what could be wrong lol.

Comment: Very funny sir. Instead of you i waited until i got more informations. It has to be a wrong path based on the information i got from the comments.

Comment: head.php is in include folder and the file i'm working on is in the root of application. **C:\wamp\www\doctorphoneshopCopy\new\include\head.php** while the file i'm working on is **C:\wamp\www\doctorphoneshopCopy\new\compare.php** , **C:\wamp\www\doctorphoneshopCopy\new\show.php** . As said head.php contains database information such server name, username, password, and some styling, so if i include it incorrectly, my application would be unstyled and database query error as well.

Comment: With this file structure it has to work.

Comment: Silly me!!!! The show.php file is

    <?php include('head.php');?><?php $text=$_POST["data"]; echo $text;?>

The include('head.php') should not be here!

Million sorry for that, and Million Thanks for all your help....

Comment: Yeah as i said a wrong poath. Please accept my answer then by clicking the button on the left side of it. THanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `dirname(__FILE__).'/'.` as path instead in your include files.

Comment: You post a answer without actually know where the problem is? Seems legit.

Comment: I have had alot of problems before with php & includes so I talk just in matter of experience.

Comment: Still, you just guess. You can't post a solution without knowing the problem.

Comment: You're right sir, however people often overlook comments and look the solutions beneath it. I am just trying to help this person. My apologies if this wasen't the correct way in your eyes.

Comment: I used: `<?php include(dirname(__FILE__)."/"."include/head.php");?>` and got the same error

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly adressing the path you currently have ? That patch of code is for paths INSIDE your include file btw. That might give errors too.

Comment: @user2273145: Take a look at my answer